# How does the cardinality of the set of all functions from $A$ to itself relate to that of $A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If $A$ is a set with cardinality $c$, what can we say about the cardinality of the set of all functions from $A$ to itself?

Comment: **Hint:** $c=0$ and $c=1$ are special cases, but otherwise: diagonalize!

Comment: @Henning: Really just $c=1$ is the special case.

Comment: @Asaf: The conclusion may be the same when $c=0$, but the _argument_ for it still needs a special case.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by diagonalize.

Comment: @Vik78: Have you seen Cantor's diagonal proof?

Comment: @Henning: Actually no. It may seem like a special case, but it's the same argument only now you're appealing to vacuous truths.

Comment: @Asaf: Perhaps we're thinking of different arguments -- the one I have in mind starts with "Choose $x,y\in A$ such that $x\ne y$ ..." and that's hard to defend if $|A|=0$. Inthe $|A|=0$ case it turns out we never actually need to _use_ those $x$ and $y$, but to skip choosing them for that reason would in itself be a _special case_.

Comment: @Henning: I see. I guess I was more or less on the same page, only without the need to choose those elements from the get go. But yeah, I guess it's easier to lump $0$ into the special cases.

Comment: @Asaf: Easier _and_ allows us to stay within ZF.

Comment: Please go more in depth as to what you mean by diagonalize.